# Powershell - Getting advanced eventlog informations (xml?)

Tags: xml, windows, powershell, event-log

I need to read specific informatiosn from eventlog. 
For example - Security log, ID 4648. With simple "Get-Eventlog" i can't get informations like TargetUserName or TargetDomainName in easy way - only from .message value, but it's way harder to read one/two informations from full text. Can i read this from XML eventlog, without exporting log to file?

[image: XML eventlog]

Answer (score 3):

Using the `Get-WinEvent` cmdlet, you can grab the XML Event data and create your output from there.

Below code does exactly that and returns an array of PsCustomObjects with all event properties found.

```
$result = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Security";Id=4648} -MaxEvents 100 | ForEach-Object {
    # convert the event to XML and grab the Event node
    $eventXml = ([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event
    # create an ordered hashtable object to collect all data
    # add some information from the xml 'System' node first
    $evt = [ordered]@{
        EventDate = [DateTime]$eventXml.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime
        Computer  = $eventXml.System.Computer
    }
    $eventXml.EventData.ChildNodes | ForEach-Object { $evt[$_.Name] = $_.'#text' }
    # output as PsCustomObject. This ensures the $result array can be written to CSV easily
    [PsCustomObject]$evt
}

# output to screen
$result

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv D:\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using as described here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/data-mine-the-windows-event-log-by-using-powershell-and-xml/

and here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2013/08/28/powershell-get-winevent-xml-madness-getting-details-from-event-logs/

Which go into detail to achieve what you're looking for, additionally you can look further into the `Get-EventLog` cmdtlet: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell has a commamnd "Get-EventLog", which is described in this URL: "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1"